# How to display a TextField after pressing a button?

Tags: flutter

I want to add a *report* usecase to a *post* feature on my app. The user can report a comment if he sees something wrong with it. He presses on the three dots shown below:

[image]

And then he should have a **TextField** so that he can input his report comment. This **TextField** should only be visible if the user clicks on the report button and should dispear when the user finishes writing his report comment and presses on the *Okay* button. A solution that I find is to make that **TextField** a floating one, like a snackbar, it appears, gives to the user the hand to write a comment, and dispears. But the issue is I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: protect your privacy. Don't show private information in your questions. Your email should be blurred out or blacked out.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal using this code with your customization,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bottom Sheet Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void _showBottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: 200,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: TextField(),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Okay'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _showBottomSheet,
          child: Text('Show Bottom Sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I modify your code in order to display the text field in the middle of the screen instead of the bottom of the screen ?